# Javascript, basic associative array

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I have a simple string and i split it into an array:

```
var alphabet = "a,b,c,d,e";
var letters = alphabet.split(",");

var dict = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++ ) {
    dict[ letters[i] ] = true;
}
```

What stumps me is that when i do a

```
console.log(dict[letters[0]] +"|"+ dict["a"]);
```

I get

```
//true|undefined
```

I dont understand the difference between letters[0] and "a". And i'm absolutely sure that letters[0] and "a" are both type of string.

EDIT: I just tried changing variable "dict" from the square brackets to the curly ones but it still gives me undefined.

EDIT 2: The below code is what im working with. "dictionary.txt" is a text file containing some 90k words separated by "\n". In this text file, the letter "a" is on the first line.

```
$.get( "tiles/dictionary.txt", function( txt ) {
// Get an array of all the words
var words = txt.split( "\n" );
// And add them as properties to the dictionary lookup
// This will allow for fast lookups later
for ( var i = 0; i < words.length; i++ ) {
    dict[ words[i] ] = true;
}
console.log(dict[words[0]]+"|"+dict["a"]);
});
```

Maybe i should have just started out with this, instead of trying to make a simplified version of it.

Comment: My local Node.JS and the JSFiddle created by @Ajwhiteway both work as written, so it's not the code.  What implementation of JS are you using?

Comment: @MarkReed hi Mark please see my EDIT 2, thank you. I am not sure what JS im using, but im on Netbeans 8.0.2

Comment: So none of the lines of the file is just `a`. Perhaps there is whitespace besides the newline?

Comment: add 1 line to your test code both version `console.log(words[0] == "a")`

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful huh interesting, I didnt think to test that. It turns out to be false.

Comment: @MarkReed I dont know if this is allowed, but i have posted the dictionary file in my dropbox [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16966255/dictionary.txt)

Comment: Why are you using netbeans btw. ? If you are looking for an editor you can also use jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Vibol this is pretty strange. This is just a guess but it may have something to do with the size of the object. Try cutting the number of words to a small amount (100 words maybe?) and see if that works.

Comment: @Vibol This bugs bothering me like crazy. I tried on my own environment with my own text file and I'm getting the same issue. I'd love for this question to get more visibility.

Comment: The issue is carriage returns.  See my edited answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your text file has carriage returns.  Splitting on newline (`"\n"`) doesn't remove the carriage returns, so the first element of the array is not `"a"` but `"a\r"`.  If you modify your code to the following, it should work, as it does in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markjreed/pvLp3xs8/):

```
$.get("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16966255/dictionary.txt",
      function(txt) {
        var words = txt.split("\r\n");
        var dict = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
          dict[ words[i] ] = true;
        }
        alert(dict[words[0]]+"|"+dict["a"]);
      });
```

Instead of requiring the file to contain carriage returns, you could split with a regular expression that matches whether it does or not:

```
var words = txt.split(/\r?\n/);
```

But if you plan on using a much larger file, note that splitting with a regex is noticeably less efficient than splitting with a constant string.

Also, while I have changed the initialization of `dict` from `[]` to the more standard `{}`, that was not the problem; an Array is just a particular type of Object, and every Object in Javascript is really an associative array.

Comment: *"every Object in Javascript is really an associative array"* I wouldn't say that. Objects are more like dictionaries or maps. "Associative array" implies a certain order of the elements, which is not the case for object properties. Actually, any comparison of objects to another data structure is probably wrong.

Comment: @Mark-reed You're goddamn right. IF you type `typeof []` you will see `"object"`.

Comment: @FelixKling No, "associative array" does not imply ordering of elements; [it is synonymous with "dictionary" or "map" in those senses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). PHP is probably the best-known implementation that actually calls them "associative arrays", and its are ordered, but that is not at all implied by the name.

Comment: Fair enough... I won't venture deeper because it only gets more confusion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure vs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type, etc)

Comment: Ahh, you have satisfied my curiosity. This is the correct answer. +1

Comment: @MarkReed sorry that i replied late, but this is the solution that ive been looking for. I just needed to add the "\r" in the split. Thank you Mark!

Answer (score 3):

Your `dict` var needs to be an object, not an array. In JavaScript, associative arrays are JSON objects.

```
var dict = {}; // Curly braces, not square brackets.

for ( var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++ ) {
    dict[ letters[i] ] = true;
}

console.log(dict[letters[0]] +"|"+ dict["a"]);
```

You will get

```
// true|true
```

Comment: It's more conventional to use the object literal syntax `{}`, but it absolutely still works if you use the array literal syntax `[]` instead.  Try before dismissing..

Comment: @MarkReed while it technically 'works', it is just adding keys to the array object, not adding array items. The length is 0, and iterating on it will cause some unexpected results. It should be an object literal.

Comment: It's not best-practice, but it doesn't explain the problem seen in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code as it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and it logged true|true. You could try changing

```
dict = [];
```

to

```
dict = {};
```

on your local implementation to see if it corrects your problem.

Answer (score -2):

Javascript doesn't support associative arrays. If you declare it with [], all indexes must be numbers.